# Redis cache in a clustered web farm? Sync between two member nodes?

Tags: redis

Ok, so what I have are 2 web servers running inside of a Windows NLB clustered environment.   The servers are identical in every respect, and as you'd expect in an NLB clustered environment, everybody is hitting the cluster name and not the individual members.   We also have affinity turned off on the members in the cluster.

But, what I'm trying to do is to turn on some caching for a few large files (MP3s).   It's easy enough to dial up a Redis node on one particular member and hit it, everything works like you'd expect.   I can pull the data from the cache and serve it up as needed.

Now, let's add the overhead of the NLB.   With an NLB in play, you may not be hitting the same web server each time.   You might make your first hit to member 01, and the second hit to 02.   So, I'd need a way to sync between the two servers.   That way it doesn't matter which cluster member you hit, you are going to get the same data.

I don't need to worry about one cache being out of date, the only thing I'm storing in there is read only data from an internal web service.

I've only got 2 servers and it looks like redis clusters need 3.  So I guess that's out.

Is this the best approach?  Or perhaps there is something else better?

Reasons for redis:  We only want the cache to use in-memory only.   No writes to the database.  Thought this would be a good fit, but need to make sure the data is available in both servers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have redis multi master (writing on both). And I might say it's replication is blazing fast (check the slaveof command of Redis).

But why you need it in the same server? Access it as a service. So every node will access the actual data. If the main server goes down, the slave will promptly turn itself into a master.

One observation: you might notice that Redis makes use of disk in an async way. An append only file that it does checkpoint depending on the size from time to time so.

Comment: Mostly it's a resource thing.   I want the servers for redundancy, but the usage is quite small, so why serve up an entire server for just the cache?  The overall usage of the current web server cluster is very small.   If it got to the point where we have decent volume on it then we definitely would look at spinning off the caching part to their own servers...

Comment: Nick, so you would setup one node in each server. One as master and the other as slave. So you would have redundancy in place without extra cost

Comment: So what happens when I reboot 01 (Master)?  Will 02 become the new master and 02 will become the slave when it comes back online?   I can buy into that.

Comment: That being the case, what would I look at to figure out how to make this a mirrored kind of system?   I'm assuming there is something that will promote the slave to master, etc, but what happens when original master come back online?  Etc.

Comment: It depends on the way you configure. If you use Redis sentinel (in this case you need at least 3 instances of sentinel) the promoted slave could remain master. Else master, due to it's configuration, will try to assume and become master again. Redis has a small footprint. You should give a try.

Comment: I ended up just going with stand alone caches on each server for now.   If this blows up, I'll probably just peal off the redis onto their own boxes (assuming I play the politics games and get boxes that is. ;) )